# Add submenu to an option

Tags: draw.io

I am developing a plugin for draw.io and I have the following code

```
Draw.loadPlugin(function(ui){
    if (ui.sidebar != null){
        mxResources.parse('Download=Download');
        mxResources.parse('Err=Err');
        mxResources.parse('Other=Other');

        ui.actions.addAction('Download', function() {
            

        });

        ui.actions.addAction('Err', function(){         
            

        });


        ui.actions.addAction('Other', function(){           


        });

    // Adds menu
        ui.menubar.addMenu('Extra', function(menu, parent) {
            ui.menus.addMenuItem(menu, 'Download');
            ui.menus.addMenuItem(menu, 'Err');
            ui.menus.addMenuItem(menu, 'Other');
        });
    }
    
});
```

I'm trying to insert a submenu in the Other option but I can't add it. And I don't really know how to do it

Thank you